# How to populate textbox A with a value calculated from the values of textbox B and textbox C?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 textboxes.

```
<input type="text" name="width" class="width" />

<input type="text" name="width_feet" class="width_feet" />

<input type="text" name="width_inches" class="width_inches" />
```

End-users can enter a number into textbox *width_feet* and a number into textbox *width_inches*. My aim is to perform a calculation to convert the feet and inches into mm and then populate textbox *width* with the result.

So far I have tried the following which doesn't seem to work very well because the result that populates textbox *width* is far too large.

```
jQuery('.width_feet, .width_inches').change(function() {
    var feet = jQuery('.width_feet').val();
    var inches = jQuery('.width_inches').val();
    var total_inches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    var mm = total_inches * 25.4;
    jQuery('.width').val(mm);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vvRv7/)

Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.toFixed()` to truncate the unnecessary decimal points,

```
jQuery('.width_feet, .width_inches').on('input',function() {
    var feet = jQuery('.width_feet').val();
    var inches = jQuery('.width_inches').val();
    var total_inches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    var mm = total_inches * 25.4;
    jQuery('.width').val(mm.toFixed(1));
});
```

And I would suggest you to use `input` event rather than `change`, since change event only get triggered when the focus got blurred out from the text box.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vvRv7/1/)

---

Apart from everything, your code failed to convert the string to number, that is why your calculation went crazy. Try to use `parseInt(string,radix)` to convert the string to a number.

```
jQuery('.width_feet, .width_inches').on('input', function () {
        var feet = parseInt(jQuery('.width_feet').val(), 10);
        var inches = parseInt(jQuery('.width_inches').val(), 10);
        var total_inches = ((isNaN(feet) ? 0 : feet) * 12) + (isNaN(inches) ? 0 : inches);
        var mm = total_inches * 25.4;
        jQuery('.width').val(mm.toFixed(1));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vvRv7/3/)

And I have forgot to tell about `.isNaN()` function, we have used this in our code because while parsing an empty text box's value the output would be `NAN` meaning not a number, so in our code we have handled the `NAN` by replacing it with `0`

---

As per the comment happened, you should use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` since you are dealing with floating point values.

Comment: Great about using `input` instead of `change`. But, the decimal points aren't the problem. If you see my jsfiddle, you'll see the actual result is too large which means the problem is with my calculation.

Comment: I think, you should use `parseFloat`, instead of `parseInt`

Comment: @Jashwant yeah, that's right.. since he is dealing with floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert both feet and inches to number:

```
var feet = parseInt(jQuery('.width_feet').val());
var inches = parseInt(jQuery('.width_inches').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

I have done in this js fiddle, your problem was with textbox value concatenating.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/f32rk/1/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
jQuery('.width_feet, .width_inches').on(function() {
    var feet = jQuery('.width_feet').val();
    var inches = jQuery('.width_inches').val();
    var total_inches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    var mm = total_inches * 25.4;
            jQuery('.width').val(Math.round(mm).toFixed(2));
 });
```